# How to change the color theme of Content Assist in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, themes, content-assist

[Image describes the block I need to change the color theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG728.png)
How to change the Background color and the color of the bar specifying row in Eclipse.

I tried changing the Content assist color in preferences > Colors and Fonts > Content assist background color but didn't work in JSP files.

But works in Java Files

[Java File Content assist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEXbB.png)

Comment: Which theme are you using? Which color, exactly, do you mean? And are you sure it's not the content assist foreground color that's the problem?

Comment: The theme I am currently using is Dracula JetBrains.
I am asking to change the bar's colour which indicates suggestions in the above image.
I don't know why but the effects of changing the content-assist color are not displayed in (JSP files) but takes effect in java and other files